# Isolate a value with BeautifulSoup in a bad written script

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the HTML source of a lot of different pages, like this one :

http://www.ielts.org//test_centre_search/results.aspx?TestCentreID=dd50346f-60bc-4a4f-a37f-7e3d34df0bf8
or www.ielts.org//test_centre_search/results.aspx?TestCentreID=feb563e3-43db-4d40-a6b1-223e2fb7191b
(I have 800 pages like this)

They are all in the same format. I am trying to parse the "Test Fee" value.

```
<TABLE style="BORDER-RIGHT: buttonshadow 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: buttonhighlight 1px solid; FONT: messagebox; BORDER-LEFT: buttonhighlight 1px solid; COLOR: buttontext; BORDER-BOTTOM: buttonshadow 1px solid; BACKGROUND-COLOR: buttonface" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=4 width=500>
<TBODY></TBODY></TABLE><table id="Template_ctl21_TestCentreView1_TestCentreTable" Width="400" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="https://www.ielts.org/TestCentreLogos/TestCentre/dd50346f-60bc-4a4f-a37f-7e3d34df0bf8.jpg" align="right" style="border-width:0px;" /><span class="TestCentreViewTitle">University of Canberra Test Centre</span><BR><BR><span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Address:</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody">IELTS Administrator</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody">Building 16</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody">Wilpena Street, Bruce</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody">ACT - Canberra</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody">2617</span><BR><BR><span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Tel: </span><span class="TestCentreViewBody">61 2 6201 2669</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Fax: </span><span class="TestCentreViewBody">61 2 6201 5089</span><BR><span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Email: </span><a class="TestCentreViewLink" href="mailto:ielts@canberra.edu.au">ielts@canberra.edu.au</a><BR><span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Web: </span><a class="TestCentreViewLink" href="http://www.canberra.edu.au/uceli/ielts">http://www.canberra.edu.au/uceli/ielts</a><BR><BR>**<span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Test Fee: </span><span class="TestCentreViewBody">AUD$330</span>**<BR><BR><div style="overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:visible;height:250px;;"><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr>

        </table></div><BR><span class="TestCentreViewBody"><P class=MsoNormal style="MARGIN: 0cm 0cm 0pt"><SPAN lang=EN-US style="mso-ansi-language: EN-US"><FONT size=3><FONT color=#000000><FONT face=Calibri>The IELTS office now closes at 4:00pm on Friday afternoons.<?xml:namespace prefix = o ns = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" /><o:p></o:p></FONT></FONT></FONT></SPAN></P>
<P>&nbsp;</P></span><BR></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Above is the part of the source which is of interest for us. 
What I want to parse is this :
 `**<span class="TestCentreViewLabel">Test Fee: </span><span class="TestCentreViewBody">AUD$330</span>**`

The problem is that we have a lot of different `<span>` with the same class (TestCentreViewBody) and one some pages you have 5, on others 8 and so on... So I don't know how to isolate this ?

I am looking for a way to isolate this value.

PS: I've noticed that the `<span>` before the last one seems to always contain the value that I am looking for. So what I've tried to do is :

```
LOL = findAll('span' .. with the 'class' : 'TestCentreViewBody')
Value = LOL[len(lol)-1]
```

But that doesn't seems to work .

Comment: Two questions: 1) Do all fee:s have the `AUD$` and 2) would you consider just using regex instead?

Comment: Regex is OK, and no they change from one page to another one. USD$130, AUD$99 ... and so on (a lot of different values)
Thx to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Do a find_all() on the `TestCentreViewLabel` class, run through each of them with a loop. In each iteration get the text and see if the word "Fee" occurs in it. If it does, get the *next sibling* of the current tag and its contents should be the value you're looking for.

Comment: I am gonna try that, seems interesting. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

This at least works for your supplied example given that you put the html into the string `t`:

```
import re
p = = "TestCentreViewBody\">(\w*)\$(\d*)</span>"
re.findall(p, t)
```

It does demand that there be a `$` somewhere in the fee-value and it returns tuples of currencies and values (if the amount can have decimal places you would need to modify the bit in the second parenthesis to e.g. `([0-9.]*)`.

Hope that works.

**Edit:**

If currency symbol isn't known (but there's always some symbol that is not a letter or number) and if the "Test Fee: " always comes right before you could do:

```
p = "<span class=\"TestCentreViewLabel\">Test Fee: </span><span class=\"TestCentreViewBody\">(\w*)[^\w\d](\d*)</span>"
```

But then the BeautifulSoup-solution suggested is more or less the same thing.

Comment: The thing is the currency is always changing so I can't know is there is gonna be a $ of something like that.